# python how to read bytes type data from file and convert it to utf-8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I need to read file content from test.txt and convert it to utf-8 encoding (to readable chinese).

it seems like an easy task, but using open(), codecs.open() etc, it always read the line as str type, instead of recognizing it as bytes.

```
with codecs.open(input_file, 'rb') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        print(type(line))
        # if it is bytes
        #print(line.decode('utf-8'))
```

my input file content in test.txt is exactly like below, with b' prefix, marking it as bytes type:

> b'\xe5\x95\x8a \xe6\x9c\x89 \xe4\xbb\x80 \xe4\xb9\x88 \xe4\xba\x8b \xe5\x95\x8a \xe6\x9c\x89 \xe4\xbb\x80 \xe4\xb9\x88 \xe4\xba\x8b \xe7\xbb\x99 \xe6\x88\x91 \xe6\x89\x93 \xe7\x94\xb5 \xe8\xaf\x9d \xe5\x95\x8a \xe5\x97\xaf \xe5\x97\xaf \xe5\xa5\xbd \xe5\xa5\xbd \xe5\xa5\xbd \xe5\xa5\xbd \xe5\x86\x8d \xe8\xa7\x81 \xe5\x93\x8e \xe5\x86\x8d \xe8\xa7\x81 \xe5\x97\xaf \xe5\xa5\xbd'

what I expect it as below, but needs to read the content from file:

```
>>> line = b'\xe5\x95\x8a \xe6\x9c\x89 \xe4\xbb\x80 \xe4\xb9\x88 \xe4\xba\x8b \xe5\x95\x8a \xe6\x9c\x89 \xe4\xbb\x80 \xe4\xb9\x88 \xe4\xba\x8b \xe7\xbb\x99 \xe6\x88\x91 \xe6\x89\x93 \xe7\x94\xb5 \xe8\xaf\x9d \xe5\x95\x8a \xe5\x97\xaf \xe5\x97\xaf \xe5\xa5\xbd \xe5\xa5\xbd \xe5\xa5\xbd \xe5\xa5\xbd \xe5\x86\x8d \xe8\xa7\x81 \xe5\x93\x8e \xe5\x86\x8d \xe8\xa7\x81 \xe5\x97\xaf \xe5\xa5\xbd'
>>> print(line.decode('utf-8'))
啊 有 什 么 事 啊 有 什 么 事 给 我 打 电 话 啊 嗯 嗯 好 好 好 好 再 见 哎 再 见 嗯 好
```

how can i do it ? I googled a lot, but with no luck. please help.

Comment: The `b` in the file mode actually prevents the input to be UTF-8 decoded automatically.

Comment: it isn't clear to me what the issue is. Are you telling me there is literally a `b'\xe5` in the file? What does `print(repr(open(file, 'rb').read()[:10]))` give you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, it is literally b'\xe5 in the file. and the function you provided, gives me this: 
b"b'01941c05"

Comment: OK, that's the problem. You wrote *the string representation of a `bytes` object to a file*. Right now, you would have to `eval` it to recover the object (you can in this case only because of the way that string representation is implemented). But you should fix the *source of this fundamental error*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga eval  function does the work. now it works as expected. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You should specify encoding as argument to open that is

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("test.txt", encoding="utf-8") as reader:
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
```

Comment: That, and avoid using "b" in mode parameter when opening a file if you don't want it in binary.

Comment: this will read it as a string, and you can just use `open`

Comment: reading it like this is no problem, but bytes type data is read as string, which makes it hard to decode to utf-8.